# How we get only android device mac address during searching of bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want only android device mac address which include only phones and tablet during searching of bluetooth devices in a chat app.

Comment: What codes have you tried? Show us please so we can help you.

Comment: @ChoungPham // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
    BluetoothDevice device = intent
      .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed
    // already
    if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
       + device.getAddress());
    }   But it get all the nearest bluetooth device address included phone and tab

Comment: See my answer below. Also, can you please edit your post and include the codes listed in your comment above, rather than post it in the comment field.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you already know about getting the `Bluetooth` MAC address of a listed device, but I'll list it here for completeness:

```
private static BluetoothAdapter getDeviceAdapter() {
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    return bluetoothAdapter;
}

private static String getMacAddress() {
    String macAddress = getDeviceAdapter().getAddress();
    return macAddress;
}
```

To determine whether a `Bluetooth` device is a smart phone or a tablet, do this:

```
private static boolean isPhoneOrTablet(int deviceClass) {
    // Tablets are defined as "COMPUTER_HANDHELD_PC_PDA"
    // while smart phones are defined as "PHONE_SMART"
    if ((deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.COMPUTER_HANDHELD_PC_PDA)
        || (deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_SMART)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Do whatever you want with the result of the `isPhoneOrTablet` method. The `deviceClass` parameter is derived from `BluetoothDevice.getBluetoothClass().getDeviceClass()` method.

To check multiple `Bluetooth` discovered devices at the same time, use a loop like:

```
for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
    if (isPhoneOrTablet(device.getBluetoothClass().getDeviceClass())) {
        Log.i("TESTING", getDeviceAdapter().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to send same message to multiple device one by one and devices are in queue?

Comment: argument device class is set by davice.getBluetoothClass or any other variable.

Comment: @user3848825: I have updated my answer to show where the parameter `deviceClass` is derived from.

Comment: @user3848825: You're welcome! Glad I could help. If my answer is correct, please tick it so others will know that it correctly answered your question. ;)

Comment: @choungPham i ticked..can u give me ans of this is it possible to send same message to multiple device one by one and devices are in queue?

Comment: @user3848825: You mean checking whether a device is a smart phone or tablet for all the devices found at the same time, then yes. See my updated answer.

Comment: @choungPham.. No i say after getting device mac Address send a message to each device one by one.

Comment: Okay, according to SO rules, what you have just asked is considered to be a separate question. Please post a separate SO question. In the mean time, see if this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection) answers your second question. ;)

Comment: @ChoungPhom see this question this is my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075820/how-to-send-same-message-one-by-one-to-a-multiple-device-via-bluetooth-in-androi

Comment: @user3848825: Great, thanks. Please mark my current answer off (or not) so this question can be closed (or not). As for your second question posted above, I'll have to research it a bit as I haven't done something like that in the past. ;)